# how to verify what is the current account clasp is logged in to?

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

I'm using **clasp** to develop google app scripts projects with Visual Studio Code under various google accounts. So whenever I switch project to work on, I might need to logout from the current account - `clasp logout` ,and `clasp login` in to another account.

Is there a way to check what is the current account clasp is logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use command

`clasp login --status`

Example:

> $ clasp login --status
>
> You are logged in as user@domain.com.

Comment: Full clasp reference docs can be read here: https://github.com/google/clasp#clasp